# Load balancing a static website from different locations?

Tags: dns, load, webserver, hosting, load-balancing

I have a site which just contain basic HTML pages and images only (no database). The site is visited by lots of users so I need to load balance it. I want to load balance it in different locations so even if a location is down, the other is still up. Here's what I'm thinking:

- I will get one server from US and one from EU
- I will upload exactly the same content to both US and EU
- I will set the nameservers of the domain to `US.EXAMPLE.COM` and `EU.EXAMPLE.COM`

Will this setup work in a way that a visitor will randomly point to either the US server or the EU server? Or are there better ways?

Also, in case US is down, will visitors automatically connect to EU until US is up?

Comment: Are you sure that you want load-balancing, or do you want fail-over?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle The site does well in one server but there are peak times where it is so slow. So I thought if I was to load balance, I might as well get failover too in a different location.

Comment: Do you have sufficient RAM on the box? Maybe a reverse proxy would solve your performance problems? This way you don't have the overhead of going to the filesystem all the time. You can serve your pages straight from RAM.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle I have 1GB RAM with 2GB BurstRAM

Answer (score 0):

Rule of the name server is as following ...

"Whichever Name server responds fast, visitor will be routed to that sever."

That means, if I am from Europe and eu.yoursite.com is responding me faster, I will be sent to EU server. If your EU site is busy and us.yoursite.com is responding me faster, I will be sent to US server.

So, mostly your arrangement for load balancing will work.

You should also use "[CDN Hosting](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/cdn-hosting.html)" to cache the content on various locations. Since the static content on CDN is delivered from various POPs across the globe, CDN reduces load on your main server.

CDN also accelerates loading of your static content and improves your site visitor's experience.